# xcode 15.2 giving "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" when comipliing on iPhone 15 (ios 17.0.1)

Tags: xcode15

I have been trying to compile my flutter app on xcode 15.2 on MacBook Pro M1 Pro chip. I keep on getting this error: "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code". I tried everything that I could find online and nothing works. IS this a problem with the new update or is there a setting that need to do? Here is my podfile[image]